# How to invite guest users from my portal when I am a guest user with guest inviter privileges?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD account where I have added another AD account as guest and gave him the guest inviter role.

Now I am logging in to my guest inviter AD account and would like to add guests of my own so that the original AD account will see them as guests.

I am logged in as the invited user that has a guest inviter role. I go to my portal -> Azure active directory -> Users and both the New User and the New Guest User buttons are active. I am able to invite a guest user but now when I am logging back to the original AD user, the one that invited the previous one, I can't see the guest that my guest inviter invited.

How can I do this?

Edit:
I see the answer and yet I am probably missing something.
I have made some screenshots, the description for each is below the picture:

[image: User A guest users]

I am logged in in User A, and I have a lot of guest users I added before using the new guest user button

[image: User A inside a guest user with a guest inviter role]

Still inside user A, I entered one of my guest users and gave him a guest inviter role.

[image: Invited a user inside the guest invite (user B) account]

Now I have logged in to this guest inviter role user (User B), went to users, added a new guest user (which accepted the invitation).

And now I can paste in screenshot number 1 again because nothing changed, I can't see the new user inside User A which is what I would like to see.

EDIT: Never mind, everything works I was just not in the correct directory inside User B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visible the guest user in the global admin list which has been added from another tenant or directory user that has a role of guest inviter on parent tenant or first tenant you can do it by following steps

**In Your Case**

As per your question See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Let's say you have Tenant A and Tenant B
2. Login into tenant A and add tenant B user as Guest inviter role
3. Switch to Tenant B User that you have added earlier on tenant A.
4. Now Invite another guest user.
5. Finally move to tenant A again, you will see that lastly added guest user added by tenant B user on tenant A global List.

Comment: @Contentop if the answer worked for you could mark it for helping others

Comment: Ok, I am trying your approch, installed Azure AD on powershell. Now, to clearify. When you say global address list, do you mean the all of the users that the original AD invited even indirectly? Like user A invites user B and give me a guest inviter role, now user B logs in and invites user C as guest. Now in powershell I need to connect to user B and then run Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId <User C id> -ShowInAddressList $true and that will make user A see user B in his guest users?

Comment: When I tried to do what I said above, calling Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId 6a432c37-433c-4b95-a471-c95bb8679182 -ShowInAddressList $true where the id is my actual guest id I got an error: Set-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing SetUser
Code: Authentication_Unauthorized
Message: User was not found.

Comment: @Contentop As you said "I am logged in as the invited user that has a guest inviter role" , here the login tenant is your first azure ad or second? If the tenant is first tenant, you could make it . In that case you would update my answer with that workaround.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without the powershell? I have added a screenshots of my issue. My concern is that I am approaching it the wrong way. I will re mark the answer again as soon as I get my issue fixed or at least get notified if I am doing this entirely wrong

Comment: Never mind I found the problem, Inside user B I wasn't in the directory of user A. that's it. I'll mark your answer but the truth is that the trivial approch does work for my needs, just need to change to the correct directory

Comment: @Contentop I had notice it before that you are missing the directory of the user that's why updated my answer and  made that flow chart on your case for better clarity. If you are given your question screen shot before it can be solved more faster. i always suggest to post questions with some more data like code snippet, screen shot or error message to that can be reproduce quickly. Thank you.